# Proof of $Af = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}} (Sgn \sigma) \sigma f$ is an alternating function.

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups, multilinear-algebra

If $f$ is  a $k-$linear function over a vector space $V$, then we need to prove that

$Af = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}} (Sgn \sigma) \sigma f$ is an alternating function.

While proving I am facing problem in a step.

For $\tau \in S_{k}$,
$\tau(Af)
 = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}} (Sgn \sigma) \tau(\sigma f) $

Now how the above cn be written as $Sgn(\tau) \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}} (Sgn \tau \sigma) (\tau \sigma) f $?

Which is then equated to $(Sgn \tau) Af$ proving that it is an alternating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that:

- $\tau(\sigma f)=(\tau\sigma)f$;
- $\text{Sgn}$, being a group morphism, you have $\text{Sgn}(\tau\sigma)=\text{Sgn}(\tau)\text{Sgn}(\sigma)$;
- As $\text{Sgn}:S_n\to\{-1,1\}$, you have $\text{Sgn}(\tau)^2=1$.

Comment: Thanks! but how doe we get $Sgn(\tau)$ in the expression of $Sgn(\tau) \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k}} (Sgn \tau \sigma) (\tau \sigma) f$, is it because $Sgn(\tau)^2 = 1$

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes that's how you get it! Don't forget that $\text{Sgn}(\tau\sigma)=\text{Sgn}(\tau)\text{Sgn}(\sigma)$.

Comment: I see you are interested in Differential geomtry, can i invite you to [differential manifold chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73238/differentiable-manifolds)

Comment: Oh sure! I'm honored!